# Minimize browser window

Tags: javascript

Thanks for your replies.
First I am explaining my requirement :-

I created my own minimize and maximize button in my Application.
When I click on minimize button, my application should minimize like
our application
 (If we minimize any application in our PC, that application is
displaying in our taskbar)
I want my application should display in taskbar after minimize.

I know how to resize the application to its minimum size.
But resize is not ful filling  my requirement.

Comment: How is this about javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231267

Basically, you can't do it. Window.blur() might do what you need, though.